# Can not open new Python or R notebook in Azure Machine Learning Studio

Tags: python, azure, jupyter-notebook, azure-machine-learning-service

I recently (and sceptically) started messing around with **Azure Machine Learning Studio**. When I stumbled accross the menu option for a machine learning work-flow **Open in a new Notebook** (For Python 3, 2 or R) I thought it was too good to be true:

[image]

And it most likely is, since this option is seemingly only available for the first step of the process. The option still exists in the **right-click menu** elsewhere, but it's greyed out:

[image]

Does anyone know why it is like this? Do I have to activate something in the menus, or buy some sort of a premium license? Is the functionality only available for *some* of the machine learning algorithms? Or is it just not supposed to be an available option in the menus?

By the way, if you click <kbd>Python 3</kbd> 3 in the first step, you get a corresponding Python 3 code snippet in a Jupyter Notebook where you immediately can start messing around with the dataset:

[image]

I realize that making this functionality available for each step in each and every model that anyone chooses to design would be an extremely difficult and maybe even impossible thing to do. But again, why is the option still in the menu?

Comment: I believe the option is only available on datasets (or on a Convert to CSV module) so you can explore the data in a notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the suggestion from @Jon in the comment section as well as a suggestion on [microsoft.com](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/84a33ecc-1db2-4d11-83d2-3e96f0bcfaa7/why-open-in-a-new-notebook-is-invalid?forum=MachineLearning), I added a **Convert to CSV Module** at the end. After running the experiment, **Open in a new Notebook** is available when you right clik the **Convert to CSV Module**:

[image]

What you get by clicking <kbd>Python 3</kbd> is this:

[image]

The functionality is certainly not as magnificent as I was hoping, but it's still pretty cool. If anyone knows *anything* about other possibilites or plans for future development, please don't hesitate to contribute with an answer!

Comment: Oh, nice! I didn't even think to use it on the evaluation module.

Comment: It was actually you who gave me the idea. And yes, it is pretty nice, but I'm really hoping that the ML Studio team has even bigger ambitions with the integration of notebooks.

Comment: Glad it helped! I'd have to see if there is a roadmap for the notebooks but I don't think they are actively updating ML Studio.